# Getting an error when trying to run a Maven project

Tags: java, maven, hadoop

So I'm trying to to a "clean install" on this Maven project to get familiar with hadoop. Problem is when it's building it's giving me an error that reads

[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?

My experience in building web applications is pretty limited, I never get this problem when developing purely Java projects (i.e. for school) and I don't know how to rectify it. I do know I downloaded the JDK, 1.7 I believe, so any help anyone could provide would be great.

Here's my pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>Mapr</groupId>
<artifactId>HadoopFirstProject</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3-mapr-2.1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Is that a copy/paste error or are you missing the `</project>` in your pom?

Comment: Also, Hadoop doesn't run on java 1.7 - http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HadoopJavaVersions

Comment: It says Hadoop requires Java 1.6+ , I didn't see it on the tested list but it doesn't say it's not compatible with Java 1.7 either. I also had a Maven project before when figuring out DropWizard that ran fine

Answer (score 1):

looks like you dont have a java compiler (javac) on the path, but rather a java runtime environment (a JRE).
make sure you have an environment variable called JAVA_HOME that points to the root sirectory of a JDK and that %JAVA_HOME%\bin is on the path.

you could verify thisby running `mvn -version` and looking at the output printed

Comment: so i have a JAVA_HOME variable that points to the JDK, where do I run that line though in cmd line?

Comment: @sreya - run "mvn -version" from a command line and paste the results into the question

Comment: what path do i have to be on to run that it just says it's not an acceptable command

Comment: well, maven needs to be on the path as well, and ideally you should run it in the project root directory